# Unhandled Exception when removing and adding items from ItemSource in uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp, parameters, crash

I have an ObservableCollection of user control and set it as the item source of a ListView

```
  public ObservableCollection<UC_ListItem_Open_Pinned> OpenChatList
    {
        get { return _openChatList; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _openChatList)
                return;

            _openChatList = value;
            OnPropertyChangedAsync(nameof(OpenChatList));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UC_ListItem_Open_Pinned> _openChatList { get; set; }


 <ListView MaxHeight="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenedChatMaxHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
           Loaded="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenedChatDataLoaded}"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"                                  
           SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenChatListSeletedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
           ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenChatList,Mode=TwoWay}"
           SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChatSelected}"
           IsItemClickEnabled="True"
           ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenPinnedChatListItemClick}">
 </ListView>
```

Now I have to shift the item on top of this list whenever I receive a new message. But while shifting this my application getting crashed randomly with the error - "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

```
  private async  void MoveRecentChatOnTop(AbstractChatData obj)
    {
        await DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                int openChatIndex = OpenChatList.IndexOf(OpenChatList.Where(i => i.ViewModel.OpenChatData.GetKey()
                                                            == obj.GetKey())?.FirstOrDefault());

                if (openChatIndex > 0)
                {

                    var item = OpenChatList[openChatIndex];
                    if (item != null)
                    {                           
                        var tempobj = ObjFactory.Instance.CreateUCListItemOpenPinned();
                        tempobj.SetData(obj, abstractThemeObj, ControlTypes.OPEN);
                        OpenChatList.RemoveAt(openChatIndex);
                        OpenChatList.Insert(0, tempobj);
                        _openedChatListView.UpdateLayout();
                        _openedChatListView?.ScrollIntoView(OpenChatList[0], ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Default);
                        if (SelectedChatKey != null && SelectedChatKey.Equals(obj.GetKey()))
                        {
                            OpenChatListSeletedItem = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("MoveRecentChatOnTop EX= " + ex.Message, GetType().Name);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "*my application getting crashed randomly with Parameter is incorrect error*" - this is not a technical description of an exception. Please catch the exception edit your question, and paste the actual exception (not as an image)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException with your code, but I failed. Could you please provide us a minimal sample by OneDrive or GitHub for testing?

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? Please feel free to cantact us if you have any concerns.